# Question about a subset not being a subspace in R^n

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is: "Find an example of $S_{1}$  and $ S_{2}$ which are non-subspace subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $S_{1}\cup S_{2}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$"

I'm having trouble coming up with subsets that are not subspaces in $R^{3}$.  I'm guessing I have to choose a point that is not the zero vector and is not a line passing through the origin.  Can a single point like (1,1,1) be considered a subset in $R^{3}$? I do not fully understand what a non-subspace subset really is.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The union of $x$-axis and $y$-axis is not a subspace, but is a subset.

Comment: @Sigur, how are x and y axis not subspaces? don't They contain the zero vector, but i'm not sure if they are closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Comment: I'm assuming that you are talking about linear subspaces (not topological subspaces). So, you are right. It is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

A point $(1,1,1)$ is not a subset, but the set $\{(1,1,1)\}$ whose only element is that point, *is* a subset, and that might well be one of your sets.

Similarly, $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{P\}$ where $P$ is any single point, would also be a subset that is not a subspace (why?)